# Creating subnet per availability zone using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, vpc

I need to create subnet per availability zone in particular region using **cloudformation**.

For example if the region is *Mumbai*, it is with three availability zones and the CF template should create a public and a private subnet in each availability zone: `1a`,`1b` and `1c`. Is it really possible? I have done the same using **terraform** but have no idea how can I achieve this in CF.

It would be great if someone could help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there are no loops in plain CloudFormation. Thus you **can't create** any constructs that would loop over AZs, get their IDs and create a pair of private-public subnets in each AZ.

If you really want to keep everything in CloudFormation than you would have to look at [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or [marcros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).

Both of them would require you to write your own **lambda function** that would use AWS API to get the number of AZs, their names and perform iteration to create the subnets.

If you already are using terraform successful, maybe its worth considering to keep using it, as it has loops useful in your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to write it in cloudformation. For example with Fn::If and then using Fn::GetAZs and creating the resources only if enough azs a parameter you can hardcode.

```
  PrivateSubnet6:
    Condition: Has6AZs
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: MyVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.20.0/22 
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select: 
        - 5
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "PrivateSubnet6"
```

```
  Has6AZs:
    Fn::Equals: [!Ref AWS::Region, "us-east-1"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using maps and conditions. The following map & condition set is applicable as of Apr 2023 for US regions. You can simply add all/other regions to the map to enable support. The conditions can be added to resources that would require three, four, five or six AZs to exist in the region.

```
Mappings:

  RegionMap:
    us-east-1: 
      AzCount: 6
    us-east-2: 
      AzCount: 3
    us-west-1: 
      AzCount: 2
    us-west-2: 
      AzCount: 4

Conditions:

  ThreeOrFourOrFiveOrSixAzs: !Or
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 3
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 4
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 5
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 6


  FourOrFiveOrSixAzs: !Or
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 4
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 5
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 6

  FiveOrSixAzs: !Or
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 5
    - !Equals
      - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
      - 6

  SixAzs: !Equals
    - !FindInMap ['RegionMap', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AzCount']
    - 6
```